# How to set a object property to be unique in for a object of a mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I have mongoose model of the course of something like this

```
courseName:
courseDescription:
sections[SectionSchema]
```

Now the section schema is as follows

```
sectionName:
sectionDescription:
subsections[LectureSchema]
```

LectureSchema is as follows

```
youtubeURL:
lectureName:
```

Now I want this youtube URL is unique for a single course. That is course B can have yotubeURLs which have been in Course A, but can't be repeated in course B.Different types of courses will be saved in my courses document in MongoDB. It would be of great help if someone helps me figure this out

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag of `unique: true` in your Schema, that will create an `index` and will make sure only one of a kind is saved in your document

```
{
    youtubeURL: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Comment: I do not want it to be unique for I just want it to be unique for every course. They can be multiple courses in the document. A course can have the same URLs as other course but cant is repeated in the same course.